# Connecting a touch panel display to the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: display, driver, touchscreen, input-device

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if a given touchscreen is compatible?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-can-i-determine-if-a-given-touchscreen-is-compatible)

I have two choices of touch panel display to connect to my Raspberry Pi:

- Reach Technologies SLCD43
- Amulet Technologies MK-480272C

I've worked with both of them in my Real Job(tm), and so I'm familiar with both of them. Programming them from a PC is not difficult (Win/Mac/Linux/whatever). Both of them have EIA232 serial and USB interfaces. From a HW standpoint, it would be a simple thing to connect them to the Pi via USB. But the GPIO pins also raise the possibility of a serial connection. Either way, I expect I'll be writing a driver for the connection.

Has anyone tried connecting one of these panels to the Pi yet? (Or any other panel for that matter ...) I'll be contacting the panel mfrs themselves for more information, but if someone else has already done it, then maybe I can piggyback off your work and get a touch panel up and running faster.

Comment: I would love to see how you get on, I have been thinking about buying one but they can be fairly pricey so waiting to see what luck others have with them.