# Touchscreen with Raspberry Pi

Tags: touchscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if a given touchscreen is compatible?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-can-i-determine-if-a-given-touchscreen-is-compatible)

I have just started using Raspberry Pi and for my project I would like to use a touch screen display.

I would like to to know..

1. Is it possible to use a touch screen via a DSI connector?

   - Then how?
2. Is any other way to use a touch screen with the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @sumith Did the other question answer yours?

Comment: Please accept some other answers and vote up before asking new question. (Accept answer. click on tick next to the answer you like, vote up, Clikc up button on all nice replies on the page)the answer is no then yes and I dont feel like expanding on it.

Comment: @ppumkin: I'm closing this because it's going nowhere (OP is no longer interested) and it's very similar to the other question linked.